# sudo does not preserve PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, sudo

I modified /etc/sudoers (using visudo) to keep environment variables :

```
Defaults        !env_reset

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
www ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/env
```

This works almost well : all environment variables are preserved, except PYTHONPATH !

```
www@myhost:~$ env | grep PYTHON
PYTHONPATH=/home/www/python_commons:/home/www/python_commons/django_commons/apps:/home/www
www@myhost:~$ sudo env | grep PYTHON
www@myhost:~$
```

I tried to add that in sudoers :

```
Defaults        env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"
```

But it does not help.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 : how to preserve PYTHONPATH ?

Answer (score 6):

You're very close: don't quote PYTHONPATH, as shown below.

```
Defaults    env_keep += PYTHONPATH
```

You don't need to modify env_reset.

You might also want to consider not changing sudoers at all. Instead, consider invoking sudo like this:

```
sudo PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH <command...>
```

This also works with PATH and other variables. When expanded by the shell, you get literal paths as though you'd typed

```
sudo PYTHONPATH=/home/www/python_commons:... <command>
```

but only when you explicitly request to pass it (as opposed to implicitly with env_keep).

This works because sudo allows you to pass existing environment variables, which requires env_keep, or to specify env variables to be set solely for the sudo command, which does not require env_keep.  Consider this:

```
snafu$ sudo grep Def /etc/sudoers
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep += SE_ok
Defaults    env_keep += SE_ik

snafu$ SE_o=outer SE_ok=outer_keep sudo SE_i=inner SE_ik=inner_keep env | grep ^SE
SE_ok=outer_keep
SE_ik=inner_keep
SE_i=inner
```

This example demonstrates setting variables in sudo's calling environment (outer) and within  sudo itself (inner). Note that SE_i is printed even though there's no env_keep entry for it.  (env_keep for SE_ik is unnecessary.)  Also note that env_keep does apply to outer variables (SE_o is not printed).

[Command invocations of the form 'var=val command' are equivalent to (export var=val; command). That is, they set one or more environment variables for that command only.]